# converting irregular grid to regular grid

Tags: r

I have a set of observation in irregular grid. I want to have them in regular grid with resolution of 5. This is an example :

```
d <- data.frame(x=runif(1e3, 0, 30), y=runif(1e3, 0, 30), z=runif(1e3, 0, 30))

 ## interpolate xy grid to change irregular grid to regular

 library(akima)

 d2 <- with(d,interp(x, y, z, xo=seq(0, 30, length = 500),
                  yo=seq(0, 30, length = 500), duplicate="mean"))
```

how can I have the `d2` in `SpatialPixelDataFrame` calss? which has 3 colomns, coordinates and interpolated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use code like this (thanks to the comment by @hadley):

```
d3 <- data.frame(x=d2$x[row(d2$z)],
                 y=d2$y[col(d2$z)],
                 z=as.vector(d2$z))
```

The idea here is that a matrix in R is just a vector with a bit of extra information about its dimensions. The `as.vector` call drops that information, turning the 500x500 matrix into a linear vector of length 500*500=250000. The subscript operator `[` does the same, so although `row` and `col` originally return a matrix, that is treated as a linear vector as well. So in total, you have three matrices, turn them all to linear vectors with the same order, use two of them to index the `x` and `y` vectors, and combine the results into a single data frame.

---

My original solution didn't use `row` and `col`, but instead `rep` to formulate the `x` and `y` columns. It is a bit more difficult to understand and remember, but might be a bit more efficient, and give you some insight useful for more difficult applications.

```
d3 <- data.frame(x=rep(d2$x, times=500),
                 y=rep(d2$y, each=500),
                 z=as.vector(d2$z))
```

For this formulation, you have to know that a matrix in R is stored in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order#Column-major_order). The second element of the linearized vector therefore is `d2$z[2,1]`, so the rows number will change between two subsequent values, while the column number will remain the same for a whole column. Consequently, you want to repeat the `x` vector as a whole, but repeat each element of `y` by itself. That's what the two `rep` calls do.

Comment: I think `data.frame(x = d2$x[row(d2$z)], y = d2$y[col(d2$z)], ...)` is slightly clearer.

Comment: @hadley, I agree, incorporated your suggestion into my answer.